# Clean up Traefik CRDs

Tags: kubernetes-helm, traefik

I've run a `helm delete` for my Traefik install on Kubernetes however I'm still seeing CRDs in the cluster.

How do you get rid of these?

Comment: there is no automated way to cleanup, you can delete one by one/automate with a simple bash script, [here](https://github.com/traefik/traefik-helm-chart/tree/master/traefik/crds) are the files of CRD, you might want to execute against `kubectl delete -f <file>`

Answer (score 0):

First, find and remove all created custom resources (for example ingressroute):

```
kubectl get ingressroute -A
```

After that, you can remove all CRDs with just one line:

```
kubectl get crds -A -o name | grep traefik | while read ln; do kubectl delete $ln ; done
```

Answer (score -1):

CRDs can be deleted just as any other object in Kubernetes: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/extend-kubernetes/custom-resources/custom-resource-definitions/#delete-a-customresourcedefinition

```
kubectl get <crd-name> -o yaml > crd.yaml
kubectl delete -f crd.yaml
```

Comment: This is overkill. You can just run `kubectl delete <crd-name>`